# POST request containing ascii characters [x-www-form-urlencoded]

Tags: node.js, post, request

I already read a lot of questions but none is solution for my problem.

I'm trying to submit a form where the charset of the page is ISO-8859-1. I'm using [github.com/request/request](https://github.com/request/request).

From documentation, to submit a form we basically need to:

`request.post({url:'http://service.com/upload', form: {key:'value'}}, function(err,httpResponse,body){ /* ... */ })`

I try it but the ascii characters wasn't right.
The page doesn't accept what I'm sending:

```
var options = { 
  url: formData.action,
  encoding: 'ascii',
  form: { username: 'teste', password: '23dçkasã' }
}

request.post(options, function...)
```

I try also:

```
var options = { 
  url: formData.action,
  headers: { 
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=iso-8859-1'
  },
  form: { username: 'teste', password: '23dçkasã' }
}

request.post(options, function...)
```

**EDIT:**

I try also with `charset=Windows-1252` and with Iconv: `var iconv = new Iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1');`

Comment: How about `encoding: 'utf8',`

Comment: Tested right now and still the same error: Wrong password.
But with a alphanumeric password it works.

Comment: From this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007969/application-x-www-form-urlencoded-or-multipart-form-data?rq=1), maybe I need to change to `multipart/form-data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was on the query string:

> The password that I use for testing was `djaçf3` and the query string made by the POST request was `dja%C3%A7f3` but with ISO-8859-1 it should be `dja%E7f3`.

So I use [querystring.stringify(obj[, sep][, eq][, options])](http://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_stringify_obj_sep_eq_options) from Node and the final result is:

```
var options = { 
  url: formData.action,
  form: querystring.stringify({ username: 'xpto', password: 'djaçf3' }, null, null, { encodeURIComponent: escape })
}

request.post(options, function...)
```

> Options object may contain encodeURIComponent property (querystring.escape by default), it can be used to encode string with non-utf8 encoding if necessary.